# FluentNHibernate Mapping with same primary key

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

i have 2 tables like this:

```
TABLE ARTICLE
Id int NOT_NULL PK
Title nvarchar(50) NOT_NULL

TABLE CONTENT
Id int NOT_NULL PK
content nvarchar(MAX) NOT_NULL
remarks nvarchar(200)
```

so each article will have a content with pk id same as article pk id, then i had create domain class like this :

```
public class Article {
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual string Title {get; set;}
    public virtual Content Content {get; set;}
}

public class Content {
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual string content {get; set;}
    public virtual string remarks {get; set;}
}
```

I try to mapping these class like this:

```
public class ArticleMap : ClassMap<Article>
{
    public ArticleMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Title);
        Reference(x => x.Content).ForeignKey("Id");
    }
}

public class ContentMap : ClassMap<Content>
{
    public ContentMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.content);
        Map(x => x.remarks);
    }
}
```

i did read data to table, but end up with `NHibernate.ObjectNotFoundException`. In my case how should i map the class with no foreign key but join another table just base on same PK Id value. Could someone guide me how to make this thing works?

Comment: Why are you doing it that way instead of having a foreign key from Article to Content?

Comment: You do not have the FK specified, so did you try to use the `Column("Id")` instead of `ForeignKey("Id")`? It's just a guess though...

Comment: @ColmPrunty i just migrate it to use ORM, it's legacy table so i dont want to change it

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor still got `NHibernate.ObjectNotFoundException` :(

Comment: Are you trying to create a 1:1 relationship where some Articles have exactly one Content but not all Articles do?

Comment: @CarlBussema yup, 1:1 relationship with all article must have 1 content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're looking for a 1:1 relationship, your mapping needs to make that clear.

First, Content needs to know about its parent article. If you don't want to make the property public, you can use `protected internal` or you can use `Reveal` in your mapping. Note that in those cases, you would need a constructor that accepts the Article and an empty constructor for NHibernate.

```
public class Content {
     public virtual Article { get; set; }
      //other properties
}
```

Your mapping then is something like

```
public class ArticleMap : ClassMap<Article>
{
   public ArticleMap()
   {
      Id(x => x.Id);
      Map(x => x.Title);
      HasOne(x => x.Content).Cascade.All();
}


public class ContentMap : ClassMap<Content>
{
    public ContentMap()
    {
      Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Foreign("Article");
      HasOne(x => x.Article).Constrained().ForeignKey();
      Map(x => x.content);
      Map(x => x.remarks);
    }
}
```

See also: http://marcinobel.com/index.php/fluent-nhibernate-mapping-one-to-on-relation/

Comment: thanks, it works but i got problem when inserting : 'attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property: Article'

Comment: i've figured it out, that i need to assign `Content.Article = newArticle;`